# Turn first part of string into a number in C

Tags: c, string, parsing, int

I have a string that looks like this:

ATOM   3760  CB  GLU B 208      21.707  20.319  45.764  0.0000 2.2350

I read it in from a file.

I would like to turn 208 into an int. Note that the number could be 11208 in which case two spaces before the 208 will be occupied. I am trying the following but I keep getting a set fault. Thoughts?

```
char* line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;

int res_num;

while (getline (&line, &len, fp) != -1)
{

    sprintf(res_num,"%5.1d",atoi(line+22));
    printf("%d\n",res);

}
```

Comment: You should split your char* and then use atoi to get the value

Comment: You could also use sscanf to scan and split the string.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting a segmentation fault since you're passing the value of an un-initialized integer (`res_num`) where `sprintf()` expects the address of a destination string buffer.

You could use `strtol()` to convert the string to integer, or `atoi()`. That's not the problem, the problem is in the random memory overwrite of your `sprintf()` call.

Also the `printf()` is referencing an unknown variable `res`; are you sure the above code even compiled?

You can drop `sprintf()` and just use `printf()`:

```
printf("found %d\n", atoi(line + 22));
```

or, of course, store the number in a variable for further processing:

```
const int res = atoi(line + 22);

printf("by the way, res=%d\n", res);
```

Comment: sorry the printf is supposed to be printf("%d\n",res);

Comment: printf("%5.1d\n",atoi(line+22)); get's me the number I need but how do I assign it to a variable?

Comment: `res_num = atoi(line + 22);`

Comment: it worked! thanks! Out of curiosity though, without specify the number of spaces to consider how does it know the size of the number. For example in sprintf is very picky about the chunk of the string you are interested in.